# How to obtain the trace of maximum triangle path sum?

Tags: r

I am now struggling to solve this maximum triangle path sum problem.

This problem is from `Euler project - 18`.

```
1
8 1
1 2 1
1 5 3 1
```

I solve this case by the maximal sum and the path through which the sum is obtained.

in this case, the answer is `1+8+2+5=16` and `c(-1,1,-1)`(↓ is -1 and ↘ is 1)

I know the code by which the maximum sum is obtained.

```
chart[2, 1:2] <- chart[2, 1:2] + chart[1, 1]
for (i in 3:n) {
    chart[i, 1] <- chart[i, 1] + chart[(i - 1), 1]
    chart[i, i] <- chart[i, i] + chart[(i - 1), (i - 1)]
    for (j in 2:(i - 1)) {
        chart[i, j] <- chart[i, j] + max(chart[(i - 1), (j - 1):j])`
        }
    }
}
result <- max(chart[n, ])
```

[Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/project-euler-problem-18/)  is a explanation page of this code

But I do not know the code by which `the path` of the maximum sum is obtained.

Comment: You should solve project Euler-questions yourself. That's the point of it.

Comment: OP's question is related to figuring out the path, which is _not_ part of the Euler 18 problem - that problem only wants to know the _sum_, not the path, so it's perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always traverse back. Example:

```
n <- 4
chart <- read.table("chart2.txt", sep = " ", fill = NA, col.names = 1:n)
chart <- as.matrix(chart)
original <- chart  # keep the original pyramid

chart[2, 1:2] <- chart[2, 1:2] + chart[1, 1]
for (i in 3:n) {
  chart[i, 1] <- chart[i, 1] + chart[(i - 1), 1]
  chart[i, i] <- chart[i, i] + chart[(i - 1), (i - 1)]
  for (j in 2:(i - 1)) {
    chart[i, j] <- chart[i, j] + max(chart[(i - 1), (j - 1):j])
  }
}
result <- max(chart[n, ])
cat("The result is:", result, "\n")

#
# get the path
#
route <- rep(0,n) # route will have n elements
route[n] = which(chart[n,]==max(chart[n,],na.rm=TRUE))[[1]] # index of last max (in last row)
route[1] = 1 # top of the pyramid
for (i in (n-1):2) # starting from bottom, going to top
{
  left <- if (route[i+1] > 1) route[i+1] -1 else 1 # index of left element
  right <- if (route[i+1] < i+1) route[i+1] else i # index of right element
  route[i] = which(chart[i,]==max(chart[i,left], chart[i,right], na.rm=TRUE))[[1]] # choose the higher value
}
cat("Route: ", route)
checksum<-0;
for (i in 1:n) checksum<-checksum+original[i, route[i]]
cat("Checksum:", checksum)
```

when executed, this will print

```
Route:  1 1 2 2
Checksum: 16
```

Executing for the data for Euler (ie `n<-15`) gives

```
> cat("Route: ", route)
Route:  1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 10
> cat("Checksum:", checksum)
Checksum: 1074
```

(Of course the `route` is the actual index of the element on each line, which could easily be turned into `+1` and `-1` notation.)